# How to move a WPF UIElement from the visual tree to a FixedPage?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-tree

My MVVM application is using on-screen visual objects to render screen content to a printed document. My View has a `ContentControl` that uses `DataTemplate` resources to determine what to display, but when I try to add that content to a `FixedPage` object, I get an `ArgumentException` with the message:

> Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.

The (simplified) XAML code for the view that handles the printing looks like this:

```xml
<DockPanel>
    <!-- Print button -->
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            DataContext="{Binding Path=PrintCommand}"
            Click="PrintButton_Click" />
    <!-- Print container. -->
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
        <!-- The visual content of this is what needs adding to the FixedPage.  -->
        <ContentControl x:Name="printContentControl"
                        Content="{Binding Path=PrintMe}" />
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

... and the code behind for the print button click handler that has the problem looks like this:

```
private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get a reference to the Visual objects to be printed.
    var content = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(printContentControl, 0);
    Debug.Assert((content as UIElement) != null, "Print content is not a UIElement");

#region This doesn't work.  See below for other things that also don't work.
    printContentControl.Content = null;
    // The line below doesn't help, but tried it in case the framework
    // needed a poke to get it to update the visual tree.
    UpdateLayout();
#endregion

    // Make sure that all the data binding, layout, etc. has completed
    // before the visual object is printed by queuing the print job at
    // a later priority.
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(delegate()
    {
        // Create a fixed page to hold the content to print.
        FixedPage page = new FixedPage();

        // Add the content to print to the page.
#region Here be dragons: 'System.ArgumentException'
        page.Children.Add(content as UIElement);
#endregion

        // Send the document back to the View model for actual printing.
        var command = ((sender as Button).DataContext as ICommand);
        command.Execute(page);
    }));
}
```

I've tried the following things to solve the problem, all with no success:

- Setting the `Content` member of the `ContentControl` to null (as in the code above).
- Setting `this.Content=null`.  Screen goes blank, but still get the exception.
- Using `RemoveLogicalChild()` on various controls.  None of which worked.
- Using `RemoveVisualChild()` on the `printContentControl` and the `content` object.  Neither of those were children of the current object.
- Using `DataTrigger`s in the XAML to replace the template when the `Content` or `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` is `{x:Null}'.  No effect.

It doesn't matter if the appearance of the screen is messed up, as the `ViewModel` changes the `View` when its print command is executed.

How can I move the `printContentControl`'s visual content (or the entire control) from the `View`'s visual tree to the `ViewModel`'s `FixedPage` object?

> **Dirty work-around**
>
> By creating a wrapper class for the content to be printed, I can make the functionality work, but it doesn't answer the original question.
>
> **Wrapper class**
>
> ```
> public class PrintContentControl : UserControl
> {
>     internal UIElement GetPrintContent()
>     {
>         UIElement printContent = Content as UIElement;
>         Content = null;
>         return printContent;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **Updated XAML using the wrapper to hold the printable content**
>
> ```xml
> <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
>     <c:PrintContentControl x:Name="printContent">
>         <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ReportTemplate}"
>                         Content="{Binding Path=PrintMe}" />
>     </c:PrintContentControl>
> </Border>
> ```
>
> **Updated code behind to get the printable content from the wrapper**
>
> ```
> private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
> {
>     // Use the wrapper to get the Visual objects to be printed.
>     UIElement content = printContent.GetPrintContent();
>     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(delegate()
>     {
>         // Works fine now.
>         FixedPage page = new FixedPage();
>         page.Children.Add(content as UIElement);
>         var command = ((sender as Button).DataContext as ICommand);
>         command.Execute(page);
>     }));
> }
> ```